# Al abrir popup con un evento onclick carga en el segundo click la función

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup

El problema con el código, es que debo hacer click dos veces en el link para que cargue la función y abra el popup.

¿Qué me sugieren?

Gracias de antemano a todos.

**Código:**

```
function PrivacyPopUp() {
    var modalprivacy = document.getElementById('myModalPrivacy');
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnprivacy");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeprivacy")[0];
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modalprivacy.style.display = "block";
    }
    span.onclick = function() {
        modalprivacy.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modalprivacy) {
            modalprivacy.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Los cambios que te sugiero son que pongas `document.getElementById("closeprivacy");` en ves de `document.getElementByClassName("closeprivacy");`

así lo hice yo y me funciona:

```
function PrivacyPopUp() {
            var modalprivacy = document.getElementById('myModalPrivacy');
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnprivacy");
            var span = document.getElementById("closeprivacy");
            btn.onclick = function() { modalprivacy.style.display = "block"; };
            span.onclick = function() { modalprivacy.style.display = "none"; console.log("close");};
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modalprivacy) {
                    modalprivacy.style.display = "none"; 
                } 
            }

        };
        PrivacyPopUp();
```

Declara la función PrivacyPopUp(); después de cargar todo

Answer (score 0):

yo te aconsejaria que no hagas una funcion en este caso, visto que lo que estas haciendo es capturar un evento.

tu codigo tendria que quedar asi :

```js
var modalprivacy = document.getElementById('myModalPrivacy');
     var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnprivacy");
     var span = document.getElementById("closeprivacy");
     btn.onclick = function() { modalprivacy.style.display = "block"; };
     span.onclick = function() { modalprivacy.style.display = "none"; console.log("close");};
     window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (event.target == modalprivacy ) {
             modalprivacy.style.display = "none"; 
         } 
     }
```

```css
#myModalPrivacy{
    display: none;
    background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="myModalPrivacy"><span id="closeprivacy">Cerrar</span></div>
<button id="myBtnprivacy">Abrir</button>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos